# Troubleshooting issue with Ansible kubevirt dynamic inventory plugin to construct new groups

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

Dynamic inventory lists have sporadic documentation so I might be doing something wrong. Given a simple inventory, I think this should construct new groups:
00_kubevirt.yaml

```
plugin: community.kubevirt.kubevirt
connections:
  - namespaces:
      - ipsecgw
```

constructed.yaml

```
plugin: constructed
conditional_groups:
  ipsecgw: "'vm' in object_type"
```

in folder `inventory`

```
root@86c5070aec4d:/# ansible-inventory -i inventory --graph
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: COMMAND_WARNINGS option, the command warnings feature is being removed. This feature will be 
removed from ansible-core in version 2.14. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in 
ansible.cfg.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /inventory/constructed.yaml as an inventory source
@all:
  |--@label_app_kubernetes_io_instance_virtual_machines:
  |  |--ipsecgw-ipsecgw01-08519f86-efd5-4165-aa77-7d604436f148
  |--@label_app_kubernetes_io_name_dp_lab_ryan:
  |  |--ipsecgw-ipsecgw01-08519f86-efd5-4165-aa77-7d604436f148
  |--@label_app_io_ansible_group_ipsecgw:
  |  |--ipsecgw-ipsecgw01-08519f86-efd5-4165-aa77-7d604436f148
  |--@label_app_io_name_ipsecgw:
  |  |--ipsecgw-ipsecgw01-08519f86-efd5-4165-aa77-7d604436f148
  |--@label_kubevirt_io_domain_ipsecgw01:
  |  |--ipsecgw-ipsecgw01-08519f86-efd5-4165-aa77-7d604436f148
  |--@label_kubevirt_io_nodeName_knode02:
  |  |--ipsecgw-ipsecgw01-08519f86-efd5-4165-aa77-7d604436f148
  |--@label_io_vm_true:
  |  |--ipsecgw-ipsecgw01-08519f86-efd5-4165-aa77-7d604436f148
  |--@rancher_prime_iad0_com_k8s_clusters_c_vqfrr:
  |  |--@namespace_ipsecgw:
  |  |  |--@namespace_ipsecgw_vms:
  |  |  |  |--ipsecgw-ipsecgw01-08519f86-efd5-4165-aa77-7d604436f148
  |--@ungrouped:
```

I can't debug this. I don't know the order of operations or why constructed seems to do nothing. It's supposed to be a builtin anyway. Besides enabling the plugin I didn't think I even had to explicitly call it in the inventory

This should allow me to make new groups

Answer (score 0):

You must enable plugin in ansible.cfg

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = kubevirt
```

Check  `ansible-inventory -i inventory --graph`

Comment: That's taken care of and functioning as expected. It's the parsing of the constructed inventory that's not working